# messy underbrace

Tags: equations

I have the following code:

```
        \begin{equation}
            \frac{\partial S}{\partial \epsilon^M} =
            \underbrace{ \frac{1}{2S} }_{\text{square root }} \cdot 
            \frac{1}{N} \cdot 
            \underbrace{ 2\sum_{i=1}^{N} \left[ \left( \log(\epsilon^M_i)-\log(\epsilon^S_i) \right) }_{\text{power}} \cdot 
            \underbrace{ \frac{1}{\epsilon^M_i}  }_{\text{logarithm}}
            \right]
        \end{equation}
```

That returns the following output:

[image]

It seems to me that `\underbrace` has some conflict with `left[`-`right]` type of commands.

How can I fix the code?

Comment: What did you expect? I see no conflict (just a very confusing formula).

Comment: Do you want all your underbraces on the same level?  Use \vphantom to make them all the same vertical size.

Comment: @egreg the `right]` bracket is missing -.-'

Comment: @A_C You *certainly* get at least an error from this code; the final `\right]` is completely misplaced.

Comment: @egreg the error is `extra } or forgotten \right`. but there is no forgotten `}`and `\right` is where it should be.  That's why I thought to some problems with `\underbrace`. Why do you say that `\right` is misplaced?

Comment: Matching `\left` and `\right` ***must*** be at the same level of grouping. You ***can't*** have `\left[` in the argument to `\underbrace` and the matching `\right]` outside it. Use `\biggl[` instead of `\left[` and `\biggr]` instead of `\right]`. Remove the inner `\left` and `\right` that serve no purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching `\left` and `\right` must be at the same level of grouping. You can't have `\left[` in the argument to `\underbrace` and the matching `\right]` outside it. Use `\biggl[` instead of `\left[` and `\biggr]` instead of `\right]`. Remove the inner `\left` and `\right` that serve no purpose.

According to your input you seem to want something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\newcommand{\eqstrut}{\vphantom{2\sum_{i=1}^{N}}}
\frac{\partial S}{\partial \epsilon^M} =
{\underbrace{\eqstrut \frac{1}{2S} }
  _{\substack{\text{square} \\ \text{root}}}} \cdot
\frac{1}{N} \cdot
{\underbrace{ 2\sum_{i=1}^{N} \biggl[ ( \log(\epsilon^M_i)-\log(\epsilon^S_i) ) }
  _{\text{power}}} \cdot
{\underbrace{\eqstrut \frac{1}{\epsilon^M_i}  }_{\text{logarithm}}}
\!\biggr]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't think this markup has a sensible meaning, though.